# When someone takes no use of what they know (their specialty)

Tags: sentence-request

In my language there is a proverb which says often people take no use of what they know (especially their profession). E.g a potter (who creates mud jugs) never has a beautiful / good etc. jug himself.

I have found in some translated pages the following proverbs a long time ago. But I have no idea if they are natural to an AmE native speaker.
If not, then please let me know how shall I indicate it in a normal language:

> - Shoe makers son runs barefoot.
> - The shoemaker’s wife, goes the worst shod.

Comment: Related (not duplicate) [on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159004/the-cobblers-children-have-no-shoes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be quite a few "shoe-maker" (or "cobler") variants of the proverb carring the same meaning, for example:

> The cobbler always wears the worst shoes;
>
> The cobbler's children are the worst shod;
>
> The shoemaker's children go barefoot.

You may also find variants with other occupations, like

> A plumber's house always has a dripping tap

and

> A blacksmith's home only has wooden spoons

and a score of others with similar meaning - they are well-googled if you need that many. Where there's a will, there's a way.

Answer (score 2):

Luke 4:23
“And he said unto them, Ye will surely say unto me this proverb, Physician, heal thyself: whatsoever we have heard done in Capernaum, do also here in thy country.”

The cobbler's wife has no shoes.

A plumber's house always has a dripping tap.

A blacksmith's home only has wooden spoons.

Most AmE native speakers will recognise most of these or will have heard a variation. My handyman jokes that his house always needs work and he never gets around to it.